# one extra alarm is set by Alarm Manager

Tags: android

When I set alarm using alarm manager, and extra alarm is set. I don't know why that happens.

The results of "adb shell dumpsys alarm " shows that there is one extra alarm, here is the result:

```
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{6d76e0b type 0 when 1597496400982 ir.zima.schema}
  operation=PendingIntent{4c364e8: PendingIntentRecord{360d701 ir.zima.schema broadcastIntent}}
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{5f1e9e1 type 0 when 1912856649822 ir.zima.schema}
  operation=PendingIntent{2495306: PendingIntentRecord{d285dc7 ir.zima.schema broadcastIntent}}
Next wake from idle: Alarm{6731a0e type 0 when 1596440300037 ir.zima.schema}
operation=PendingIntent{5c68c2f: PendingIntentRecord{e088129 ir.zima.schema broadcastIntent}}
```

The strange part is that even after I deleted the method call (literally there are no alarms set by me anymore) adb still says there is one alarm set:

```
    RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{63e6995 type 0 when 1912857022688 ir.zima.schema}
  operation=PendingIntent{afc8aaa: PendingIntentRecord{943069b ir.zima.schema broadcastIntent}}
  Next wake from idle: Alarm{6731a0e type 0 when 1596440300037 ir.zima.schema}
  operation=PendingIntent{5c68c2f: PendingIntentRecord{e088129 ir.zima.schema broadcastIntent}}
```

This is the method where I set my Alarm in **AlarmManagerHelper.class**:

```
 public static void setAlarm(Context context, int requestCode, int hour, int minute){


    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context//same activity should be used when canceling the alarm
            , AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar time = getTime(hour, minute);

    //set Alarm for different API levels
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }
    else{
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Then I call this method like this:

```
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        AlarmManagerHelper.setAlarm(context,
            AlarmManagerHelper.FIRST_ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,
            17,30);
```

Do you have any idea what might be going wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

What are the long numbers? I'm guessing those are the [milliseconds since epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/)?

- 1597496400982 - GMT: Saturday, 15. August 2020 13:00:00.982 (yesterday)
- 1912856649822 - GMT: Tuesday, 13. August 2030 13:04:09.822 (in ten years)
- 1912857022688 - GMT: Tuesday, 13. August 2030 13:10:22.688 (in ten years)

Maybe you created those alarms 3 days ago (13. August) by accident or the system created them for some weird reason. Considering the lifespan of smartphone, they won't be triggered anyway.

If you want to debug it some more you could set the system clock to that time and try to get more information from the `Intent` which is passed to your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I realized when  I swipe the app away and relaunch it this alarm might goes away, but sometimes it doesnt

Comment: You could check if intent.getAction() equals your action string. Or compare intent.toString(). Just to check if the system created the alarm or if it's an exact copy of your own one. You could also try to find something about the alarm in the logcat at that exact moment. Maybe with no filters if nothing shows up.